# Are the parameters fromBlock and toBlock of getPastEvents() and events.MyEvent() inclusive or exclusive of the block number?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, events

Using Web3, are the parameters `fromBlock` and `toBlock` of `getPastEvents()` and `events.MyEvent()` inclusive or exclusive of the block number?

Answer (score 1):

It is inclusive.

`toBlock`, if not specified, defaults to `latest`, which means it will give you data up to the latest block the node has confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

It's inclusive for both.

The documentation is a bit confusing. Does not mention the word `inclusive` or `exclusive` explicitly, but here it is:

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents

`fromBlock - Number|String|BN|BigNumber (optional): The block number (greater than or equal to) from which to get events on. Pre-defined block numbers as "earliest", "latest" and "pending" can also be used.`

`toBlock - Number|String|BN|BigNumber (optional): The block number (less than or equal to) to get events up to (Defaults to "latest"). Pre-defined block numbers as "earliest", "latest" and "pending" can also be used.`

Notice the `(greater than or equal to)` and `(less than or equal to)`. The `equal to` in both `fromBlock` and `toBlock` definition tells you that they are inclusive.

Comment: Thanks! Back then (four years ago) it wasn't indicated I think.